# Динамические адреса в яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Для сайта объявлений нужна следующая функция. 
ПОльзователь вводит данные, в том числе адрес. 
Необходимо, чтобы на карте отобразился этот адрес в автоматическом режиме. 
Как этого добиться в яндекс-картах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Яндекс.Карт, [раздел 10, пункт "Поисковая строка"](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/#geocoder) - что не получается?

Comment: Как это автоматизировать?

Comment: Получили пользовательские данные, собрали адрес из разных полей (если нужно), сформировали запрос к API, отправили его, получили результат, показали карту.

Comment: Еще вопрос. Встроил карты на сайт, теперь при загрузке из-за карт сайт подвисает. Неизвестно необходимо либо пользователю карты или нет. Как загрузить карты, только при нажатии на область карт?

Comment: Так неизвестно же как именно они подключаются. Общая рекомендация - код, в котором создаются карты:

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map(...
    ...

вызывать только явно, а не при загрузке страницы.